# Is there a way to make a screenshot to the console using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, nunit

I am trying to make a screenshot to the DevTools console when my automated test fails to see which errors occur. Is there any way to achieve this?

I am only thinking at using Keys in order to simulate pressing the F12 key but I was wondering if there is a better way.

What the screenshot should look like is presented in the image below:
[image]
I want to basically see these errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a tool that can report the results?

Comment: I don't know which tool can do this 

Comment: https://smartbear.com/blog/selenium-report-generation/

Comment: Browser vendors provide ways to get information from the dev tools console. Can you [edit] your question to include information about what you want from the dev tools console? There might be an existing API that better suits your needs.